# Discount Rule Gets Deactivated Randomely

Tags: discount

I have created one discount rule for entire store. As per the rule the all products are sold with 15% off. There is no other rule at any level.

This rule gets deactivated randomly. To again activate it, I have to run reindex command using ssh.

Just to try I created one cron job for reindexing by reading some article. This cron job runs at every 12hrs.

Issue not resolved.

Thanks,
Niraj

Comment: Which magento version?

Comment: I am using Magento ce 2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

There might be three issues:

1. The cron is not running
2. The cron is running, but the execution of the discount rule task has
   been blocked by another task.
3. The cron server timezone and your local timezone are not being
   aligned.

To solve this issue, you can try using [AOE Scheduler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler) extension. It helps you to to visualize the timeline of the execution of the cron jobs. As a result, you can identify the issue that is causing your discount rules to get deactivated randomly.